# How to predictably run shell script in unknown user environment?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

### Summary

How can I guarantee that my shell scripts will do what I expect, regardless of the environment?

(Let's assume that people have `alias`'d and `function`'d everything they can, but that they haven't touched any system binaries eg. `/bin/ls`)

### Explanation

I am distributing shell scripts as part of an app. These shell scripts are executed in the user's environment - this cannot be changed.

This means users may have aliases for anything and functions redefining "standard" behavior. There have already been a few cases when normal shell keywords have been redefined (eg. `local`), causing unexpected side effects and crashes.

The only tokens that *cannot* be defined as functions are as follows:

Bash:

```sh
!  [[  ]]  case  coproc  do  done  elif  else  esac  fi  for  function  if  in  select  then  time  until  while  {  }
```

ZSH:

```
!  [[  case  coproc  do  done  elif  else  end  esac  fi  for  foreach  function  if  nocorrect  repeat  select  then  time  until  while  { }
```

I am aware that:

- You can escape a word to skip alias lookup
- You can use `builtin` to always run a builtin
- You can use `command` to always run a command

However, `builtin` and `command` can be redefined, so `\builtin <command>` may not always do what I expect.

Comment: You can turn off alias expansion. (Bash normally turns it off when the session is not interactive, which should be the case with a script, but it doesn't hurt to turn it off explicitly.) bash: `setopt -u expand_aliases`. zsh: `unsetopt aliases`.

Comment: @rici You mean `shopt` (bash)? `shopt` is not a bash reserved word and could as well be redefined as a function. Try `function shopt { echo foo; }; export -f shopt` and then execute a bash script containing just `shopt`...

Comment: @Rob: You have to write it in a way that it does not depend on any environment variables except those you set by yourself. For instance, if your script invokes some command _C_, you can not simply write _C par1 par2 ..._, because this assumes that C is contained inside the PATH. Hence, the first step in you script would be remove everything from the environment, and the define the environment variables which you need by yourself.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: But functions are not inherited to child processes! Even if the process invoking the script, would define a function _shopt_, the called script would not see it.

Comment: @user1934428 Give it a try, I shown the commands to execute. And don't worry, after executing the script you can simply `unset -f shopt` to recover the built-in.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: I see: You use bash exported functions.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, and nothing guarantees that the OP's users will not do the same.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : Right!! I added something about this issue to my answer.

Comment: @renaud: good point. It's not clear to me how these scripts are being run. You can also turn off alias expansion with a command-line option. Also, alias expansion does not occur inside a function; if it happens, it happens when the function is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are not expanded in bash scripts (unless you explicitly request this), and functions are usually not inherited by child processes. The caller of your script just has to avoid **sourcing** it. Problems could be environment variables and file handles.

It is difficult to make a script completely self-containing. For instance, I have seen cases where even standard programs (`ls`, `cat`,....) are stored in different locations, which means that if you set up your own PATH and don't know anything about the target platform, you have to apply some heuristics (searching a list of "commonly known directories") and hope that your search is correct.

A more reliable way would be to require from the **user** of the script to provide a certain minimal configuration (typically containing the basic definition for a PATH) and pass this configuration as parameter to your script.

There is one problem pointed out in the comment by Renaud Pacalet, in that bash allows functions to be exported (using `export -f`), and in bash, you would have to find out which functions exist, and explicitly remove their definitions (similarily as you would do it with environment variables). However, I see that you have tagged your question by *bash* and *zsh*, and if you don't mind, which script language you are using, writing the script in `zsh` would be perhaps better, because zsh does not have exported functions.

One point to keep in mind is, that every shell, bash and zsh, processes on startup certain files, before the commands in your script have any chance to run. For instance, no matter how you start your zsh, it will always process `/etc/zshenv`.  For instance, if your script at one point invokes a `zsh` child script too, it would again run /etc/zshenv.

Of course, those startup files **could** set up functions, and in zsh, aliases are (AFIK) even expanded inside scripts. The strategy would be therefore to initially loop over your environment variables, the currently defined functions, the currently defined aliases (in zsh), and remove those definitions. Then you set up your own definitions (functions, variables).